# How to replace words in a string easier in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string, text, replace, nsstring

So I have a text field where the user can type in anything. I use the following code to assign the input an NSString value:

```
NSString *input = _inputTextField.text;
```

If the user has the word "smart" anywhere in the input, than it will replace it with "clever". Likewise, if they have "smarter" it will replace it with "cleverer". I have the following code to achieve this:

```
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"smart" withString:@"clever"];
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"smarter" withString:@"cleverer"];
```

Now this works perfect, BUT I ran into a problem while running the app. If the user has ANY word that contains "smart", for example, "smartweed", than it will make it into "cleverweed", which is not even a word. In order to bypass this, I added the following code:

```
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"cleverweed" withString:@"smartweed"];
```

Now, I know I don't have to do that to EVERY word that exists that has "smart" into it, so I changed the code to say this:

```
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" smart " withString:@" clever "];
```

Hey, that fixed it. But then I ran into a problem... it won't fix it if the word " smart " is the beginning of a sentence, or the last one of a sentence! I can fix it by adding this:

```
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Smart " withString:@"Clever "];
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" smart." withString:@" clever."];
```

And so on with whatever the sentence ended.

Now, my official question is, is there a way where the code will just replace "smart" into "clever" without it changing the word "smart" that appears inside other words? I've looked at NSRange, but I'm confused how to properly use it here since it can depend on whatever the user inputs.

Also, I've tried searching for this and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is actually not very clear (what does the text field mentioned in the title have to do with it?), and under the hood it deals with natural language processing which is a *big* topic.

Anyway, for the straight substitution that solves the problem you mention, you can use a regular expression:

```
NSString *text = @"This is a smart dog that avoids eating the smartweed";

NSString *pattern = @"(?wi)\\bsmart\\b";

NSString *result = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: pattern
                                                   withString: @"clever"
                                                      options: NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                        range: NSMakeRange(0, [text length]) ];
```

The `\b` identifies a word boundary in a regular expression and `w` in the parenthesis will make it handle word boundaries according to unicode (rather than traditional regex rules) while the `i` makes the search case insensitive. Notice, though, that while the search is case insensitive,  the replacement will still be the literal string that you enter - i.e., lower case in this example.

The problem you will run into is maintaining capitalisation, handling plurals, etc. so at the end of the day you will want to use a more powerful framework.

Comment: My first line of code answers your question. It has to do that the input of the TextField, which is whatever the user types is, are the words that will be replaced. The user can type in a paragraph, and the code will search the words he put. THIS works perfect! And yes you're right, I will run into capitalization. I've been trying to use case insensitive and every solution I find, my xcode always gives me an error that I cant use case insensitive even when I copy the code the same.

Comment: @BringMe115 my comment about the relevancy of the text field referred to the fact that your code only deals with strings, really. That they come from a text field is not really relevant. Added the option for case insensitive search.

Comment: Either way, you gave me a much easier approach that will involve me getting rid of a bunch of unnecessary lines of code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for nonletter+"smart"+nonletter, wherein non letter is optional.

Typed in Safari:

```
NSString *string = @"smart and smartweed and smart"; // From text field
NSString *searchWord = @"smart";
NSString *newString = @"clever";
NSRange wordRange;
NSCharacterSet *letters = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange( 0, [string length]);
while ((wordRange=[string rangeOfString:searchWord options:0 range:searchRange]).length!=0)
{
  NSLog(@"%@<%@>", [string substringToIndex:searchRange.location], [string substringFromIndex:searchRange.location]);
  BOOL hasLetterAhead = YES;
  if (     (wordRange.location==0) 
       || !([letters characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:wordRange.location-1]]))
  {
    hasLetterAhead = NO;
  }

  BOOL hasLetterBehind = YES;
  if (     (wordRange.location+wordRange.length>=[string length]) 
       || !([letters characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:wordRange.location+wordRange.length]]))
  {
    hasLetterBehind = NO;
  }

  if (!hasLetterAhead && !hasLetterBehind)
  {
    string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:wordRange withString:newString];
    searchRange.location = wordRange.location + newString.length;
  }
  else
  {
    searchRange.location = wordRange.location + wordRange.length;
  }
  searchRange.length = [string length]-searchRange.location;
}

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Leads to:

```
2014-06-13 13:54:41.702 kkk[4216:303] <smart and smartweed and smart>
2014-06-13 13:54:41.703 kkk[4216:303] clever< and smartweed and smart>
2014-06-13 13:54:41.704 kkk[4216:303] clever and smart<weed and smart>
2014-06-13 13:54:41.705 kkk[4216:303] clever and smartweed and clever
```

The Code searches for the range of the string. Then it looks, whether it starts at the beginning of the text or does not have a character ahead of it. It does the same at the end. Please check for the correct index calculation yourself. :-]

Comment: So I'm trying to make it work, but it keeps telling me "Expected )" on line 14 where the "{" is before the "letterBehind = NO;

Comment: The error occurs after it tells me to fix line 5 to add an "]"

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but this actually works exactly the same as replacing "smart" with "clever" and it also does it even inside words that contain "smart." And it actually freezes if I put "smart" at the end of the sentence.

Comment: No, it doesn't it inside, but tries to replace a non-replacing word over and over instead of skipping it. Pushed an update.